# How to change the value in a dataframe using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

Here is the code I have tried, but not getting the desired output. The values which I want to change are intact. I used `df.replace`, I tried `df.rename` also, but not getting the output. I'm not getting any error but the values are not getting changed.

```
df = pd.read_excel('Energy Indicators.xls')
df.replace(to_replace=["Republic of Korea", "United States of America", "United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland", "China, Hong Kong Special Administrative Region"], value=["South Korea", "United States", "United Kingdom", "Hong Kong"])
```

Comment: Your code worked in my simulations. Could you please post the content of the DataFrame in the question?

Comment: You need to assign result back to object: `df = df.replace(...)`.

Comment: https://rqlfwsfeoxigeegzprvaik.coursera-apps.org/files/Energy%20Indicators.xls  This is link from where you can download the file. @DanielLabbe

Comment: This link is not publicly available.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `inplace=True` to mutate the original dataframe or assign the results to a new one.
Try:

```py
df.replace(to_replace=[...], value=[...], inplace=True)
# or 
df = df.replace(to_replace=[...], value=[...])
```

For example:

```py
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(
...     {
...         "countries": [
...             "Republic of Korea",
...             "United States of America",
...             "United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland",
...             "China, Hong Kong Special Administrative Region",
...         ],
...     }
... )
>>> df = df.replace(
...     to_replace=[
...         "Republic of Korea",
...         "United States of America",
...         "United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland",
...         "China, Hong Kong Special Administrative Region",
...     ],
...     value=["South Korea", "United States", "United Kingdom", "Hong Kong"],
... )
>>> df
        countries
0     South Korea
1   United States
2  United Kingdom
3       Hong Kong
```

Comment: When I tried df = df.replace(....) not all the values in the dataframe was replaced.

Comment: I suspect you have non-exact matches in your source column?